# Merging csv file's lines with the same initial fields and sorting them by their length

Tags: file, sorting, csv, unix, awk

I have a huge csv file with 4 fields for each line in this format (ID1, ID2, score, elem):

**HELLO, WORLD**, 2323, elem1

**GOODBYE, BLUESKY**, 3232, elem2

**HELLO, WORLD,** 421, elem3

**GOODBYE, BLUESKY**, 41134, elem4

ETC...

I would like to merge each line which has the same ID1,ID2 fields on the same line eliminating the score field, resulting in:

**HELLO, WORLD,** elem1, elem3.....

**GOODBYE, BLUESKY,** elem2, elem4.....

ETC...

where each **elem** come from a different line with the same **ID1,ID2.**
After that I would like to sort the lines on the basis of their length.

I have tried to do coding in java but is superslow. I have read online about AWK, but I can't really find a good spot where I can understand its syntax for csv files.
I used this command, how can I adapt it to my needs?

```
awk -F',' 'NF>1{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2}END{for(i in a){print i""a[i]}}' finale.txt > finale2.txt^C
```

Comment: Change `$2` to `$4` and that should do it.

Comment: I would like also the second field to match, which is the syntax for an additional condition like a[$1] = a[$1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your key should be composite, also delimiter need to be set to accommodate comma and spaces.

```
$ awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '{k=$1 OFS $2; a[k]=k in a?a[k] OFS $4:$4}
                        END{for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file

GOODBYE, BLUESKY, elem2, elem4
HELLO, WORLD, elem1, elem3
```

**Explanation**

set field separator (FS) to comma followed with one or more spaces, and output field separator (OFS) to normalized form (comma and one space).  Create a composite key from first two fields separated with OFS (since we're going to use it in the output).  Append the fourth field to the array element indexed by key (treat first element special since we don't want to start with OFS).  When all records are done (END block) print all keys and values.

To add the length keep a parallel counter and increment each time you append for each key, `c[k]++` and use it when printing.  That is,

```
$  awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '{k=$1 OFS $2; c[k]++; a[k]=k in a?a[k] OFS $4:$4}
                        END{for(k in a) print k, c[k], a[k]}' file | 
   sort -t, -k3n

GOODBYE, BLUESKY, 2, elem2, elem4
HELLO, WORLD, 2, elem1, elem3
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time,  could I ask you the syntactic explanation of your solution?

Comment: The thing is that I would like to add as third field also the number of elements for that specific line (ID1 ,ID2 ,length ,elem1 ,elem2,...) in a way to use that field the file's lines.